# Retrieve fields from mongodb with renamed field through pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

As similar to mongoDB code, such as

```
db.collection.aggregate({$project:{"ID_NO":"id"}})
```

Need syntax for pymongo, i have a query

```
query = dict(app_name='Test', is_enabled=True)
element_list = elementsettings.objects(**query)
```

I have tried -

```
query = dict(app_name='Test', is_enabled=True, $project={'is_app_enabled':'is_enabled'})
```

Comment: Is there an error message? what does it state? How is the mongoDB code related as in your try contains no id?

Comment: Error msg - `*** InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "$project"`. ID wrt mongoDB command is an example.

Comment: I'm sorry about incompleteness: please edit your question and include this new information. I personally have no knowledge about python or pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

`$project` should be within quotes like `'$project'` when using with Pymongo.

Comment: I got this error - `*** InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "$project"`

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```py
db.collection.aggregate([{"$project": {"ID_NO":"$id"}])
```

Note that the projection operation sits inside an array of aggregation operators. Also note that this particular project will erase all other fields.